# Zip file uploaded through Lambda+API gateway with POSTMAN is corrupted

Tags: amazon-web-services, file-upload, multipartform-data, aws-lambda, postman

I am doing following steps:

1. I have API gateway ( PUT Method) which integrated with AWS lambda.
   It is direct mapping in multipart/form-data ( so big logic is happening here )
2. Now through POSTMAN, file is being uploaded.
3. File is getting uploaded.
4. When I download this ZIP file, It says "End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not a Zip file, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part Zip file."
5. Then I opened the ZIP in notepad++ ( yes i did that ), I can see only few line with binary data, on other hand my original file has lot of it.

Please help, let me know if some more needed.

Comment: Hi Anand, Can you please share your code i'm trying to do something similar (i'm a newbie in nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turned out I was sending the request without all needed headers. It worked fine with Postman. Please check if your request contains these [postman-headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKA8L.png)